# Duplicate "default" form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this code:

```
// Add form
jQuery('.add-form').click(function() {
    // "Copy" default form
    formGroup = jQuery('.form-item').html();
    // "Paste" default form
    jQuery('#main-form').append('<div class="form-item row">'+formGroup+'</div>');

});
```

**Situation:**

- There's a form by default
- If you press the button, this code runs
- It duplicates default form & place it under default form
- If pressed again, it makes third form & places it under the second
- etc

**Problem:**

I need to store default form to code somehow - problem is that I need the new form to be with empty fields & with original DOM (it might change when fields are filled in).

**Question:**

How to store default form in code (hidden or something), so that it would always load default one?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your html code, but here is how it will work. The idea is that you keep the original hidden elsewhere.

HTML

```
<button class="add-form">add form</button>
<form id="main-form">
    <div class="form-item row">
      <input type="text" name="abc">
    </div>
</form>
<div class="stay-hidden original-form-item">
  <input type="text" name="abc">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stay-hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
// Add form
jQuery('.add-form').click(function() {
    // "Copy" default form
    formGroup = jQuery('.original-form-item').clone();
    // "Paste" default form
    jQuery('#main-form').append('<div class="form-item row">'+ formGroup.html() +'</div>');

});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u5Lomazx/1/